# AWS Glacier File Validation

Tags: amazon-glacier

I'm new to AWS Glacier and I've uploaded a pretty large encrypted file (500GB). It took around 4 days. The file exactly matches by byte to the original. My only concern is, how do I know it was damaged in the upload? Anyone know how to verify that?

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly did you upload it? The client software should have provided checksums to the service, so that that the service could have enough info to reject anything corrupted in transit, but the specifics of this will depend on how you did the upload.

Comment: I'm using FastGlacier

Answer (score 0):

> Q. How can i verify that file was uploaded correctly?
>
> A. When you upload the files, FastGlacier checks file integrity by calculating sha256 hash and sha256-tree-hash of an each part of the file and sha256-tree-hash of the entire file when completing the upload. If the hashes do not match, you will see corresponding error message and file will not be written.
>
> https://fastglacier.com/faq.aspx

See [Computing Checksums](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations.html) in the Glacier API Reference documentation for how `x-amz-sha256-tree-hash` and `x-amz-content-sha256` actually work.

Glacier re-calculates these hashes as the data comes in and will refuse to store anything that doesn't match what the client software sent... so the statement that *FastGlacier checks file integrity* is strictly not accurate -- it's actually the Glacier service that does the checking, against hashes generated by FastGlacier.